# Extend visual studio behavior using scripts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Does anybody know any extension or built-in feature, where I can place my custom script for visual studio? What I intend to do is something similar to the below:

`OnCloseSolution += function (){
    Open(Windows.StartPage)
}`

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/). See the following [extension sample](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#NoOpenedFiles) on how to access **DTE.Events.SolutionEvents**.